# How to determine public temp directory on OS X to be write-accessible by www server?

Tags: macos, folders, script, command-line

I've MAMP running `httpd` server as _www and I'd like to assign the temporary directory as part of the shell script (bash).

I've tried to use `$TMPDIR` as per these posts:

- [How do I find the 'temp' directory in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31068)
- [Where is the Temp folder in OS X?](https://superuser.com/q/581347/87805)

however it points to `/var/folders/vp/tlt7xf791gl1_v56m0xdmrph0000gn/T/` and this folder has not necessary permissions, so Apache server can't create any files in there.

Based on this:

```
$ /usr/bin/stat -F $TMPDIR /tmp /private/tmp 
drwx------ 104 kenorb staff 3536 Oct 14 22:21:05 2015 /var/folders/vp/tlt7xf791gl1_v56m0xdmrph0000gn/T//
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 11 Apr  9 13:08:03 2014 /tmp@ -> private/tmp
drwxrwxrwt 112 root wheel 3808 Oct 14 22:12:04 2015 /private/tmp/
```

My www user which I care about:

```
$ id _www
uid=70(_www) gid=70(_www) groups=70(_www),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),401(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),100(_lpoperator)
```

I can't use `/tmp`, because it's linked to my `/private/tmp` (which name states it's private).

Therefore how do I determine my correct temporary directory on OS X, so I and my `httpd` server can use it?

I don't want to hardcode value, as the script would be useless when used on different environments (e.g. on non-MAMP environment), so the location can vary.

Comment: Are you worried /private is just to "hide" the usual directories from / and not to mean you can't store files there. It's better form to use $TMPDIR instead of /tmp, but writing to /tmp is generally fine on OS X if you prefer using that fixed path...

Comment: The point of $TMPDIR being in /var/... is that it has the correct permissions - so what users is the directory open for and what user does the script run as? - private just is a historic so that the OS can be on a read only file system and /private is a mount to a local file system that can be written to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write to `/tmp` (which is equivalent to writing to `/private/tmp` ) since it's writable by all users and not just administrative users. It's there for compatibility and for bonus points, your script can clean up files or cut them if they grow too large.

I don't have an authoritative reference to why /private was called that, but it's always been open to writing and isn't restricted like $TMPDIR is from non-admin users.

The real question is what user are you running `apache` - a member of the ADMIN group or just a normal non-admin user?

Apple documents this in the [Secure Coding Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Introduction.html) with the admonition that writing files to publicly readable locations is inherently insecure and that it's better to place files in more protected locations that aren't readable by all users. See the **Race Conditions and Secure File Operations** section and this link on [creating secure temporary files](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/RaceConditions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002585-SW10). By using the [mkstemp](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/mkstemp.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/mkstemp) POSIX call you ensure a unique file is created and can control access with umask.

Oddly (to me), `mktemp` when run by a non-admin user can still make a temp file in $TMPDIR so it's clearly using escalated privileges to hand off that more "secure" file to non-admin users. Pretty cool.

Comment: Is there any variable or function which can use to determine that folder? Or I've to do conditionally?

Comment: @kenorb - which folder? -  $TMPDIR is the variable that gives the temporary folder (also TMPDIR is for all users each user has a different one /tmp is shared so you get conflicts between users)

Comment: @kenorb write to the path `/tmp` and bob's your uncle. You could make it a variable, but there's no point as it doesn't change.

Comment: I think it'll be easier to use `/tmp`, initially I was confused by the symbolic link which had `0755` on it, but the destination is actually `1777`, so I hope it'll work in all cases. Thanks.

Comment: You can't change /tmp or /private/tmp but all users can write there. Insecure, but it gets the job done with little muss or fuss. You're on it with the `1777` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

As for workaround, I've found so far that `php` command can determine the right temporary directory from the www perspective (assuming PHP CLI has
the same settings as server):

```
$ php -r "echo ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');"
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php
```

It's possible also to use `mktemp` to check where the temporary files are created for specific user (as `$TMPDIR` would fail), e.g.:

```
$ sudo -uwww bash -c 'dirname $(mktemp)'
/tmp
```

---

So in summary this could be extended to something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
WWW_USER="$(ps axo user,group,comm | egrep "(apache|httpd)" | grep -v ^root | uniq | cut -d\  -f 1)"
PHP="$(which php)"

if [ -n "$PHP" ]; then
  TMP="$(php -r "echo ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');")"
elif [ -n "$WWW_USER" ]; then
  TMP="$(sudo -uwww bash -c 'dirname $(mktemp)')"
elif [ -n "$TMPDIR" ]; then
  TMP="$TMPDIR"
else
  TMP="/tmp"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

***Short answer***: `getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR` (command line interface), or for another user, e.g. `www`: `sudo -u www getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR`.

---

**Too long; don't read** unless you want a story on how I got to the *short answer*:

On macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra, I can see the rough equivalences of `$TMPDIR` for different users, e.g. current user and `www`, in a few ways that I know of, using `bash --version` `5.1.8`:

- Each of the below blocks yields two different folders under `/var/folders` ending in `/T/`.
- `command rm` is compat for an `alias rm=…` in my `~/.bash_profile`.

1. Using `mktemp` - this is the same as [kenorb](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/22781/kenorb)'s [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210942/how-to-determine-public-temp-directory-on-os-x-to-be-write-accessible-by-www-ser/210947#210947) but oddly with a different result - also doing a cleanup:

   ```
   (sudo --validate && function inner(){ t=$(mktemp) && dirname "$t" ; command rm "$t" ;} && for u in $USER www ;do sudo -u $u bash -c "$(declare -fp inner|awk 'FNR>3{print _}{_=$0}')" ;done)
   ```
2. Reading [Apple's opensource](https://opensource.apple.com/releases/) [for my macOS version](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/distribution-macOS/tree/macos-10136)'s [package "shell_cmds"](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/tree/shell_cmds-203)'s [`mktemp`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/blob/shell_cmds-203/mktemp/mktemp.c#L104), I wrote a short program in C:

   ```
   (sudo --validate && function outer(){ for u in $USER www;do sudo -u $u $1;done;} ; cleanup(){ command rm $1 $1.c;} ; b=/tmp/$$ && cat >$b.c && clang -o$b $b.c && chmod +x $b && outer $b ; cleanup $b) << END
   #include <limits.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
    int main() {
     char tmpbuf[PATH_MAX];
     if (confstr(_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR, tmpbuf, sizeof(tmpbuf)) < 1) {
      return 1;
     } else {
      printf("%s\\n", tmpbuf);
      return 0;
     }
    }
   END
   ```
3. Writing this, after having tried `getconf _CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR` and `getconf CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR`, still not checking `man 1 getconf` as I should've, I at least finally checked my earlier usage of `confstr` - actually `getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR` - realising the transformation needed for `.c` `confstr(int name,…)` to `.sh` `getconf var`, i.e. `getconf $(sed s/^_CS_// <<< $name)`, e.g. `getconf $(sed s/^_CS_// <<< _CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR)` equal to `getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR`, thus:

   ```
   (sudo --validate && for u in $USER www ;do sudo -u $u getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR ;done)
   ```

**Too long; note to self**: read the f-ing manual - `man 1 mktemp` –› `man 3 confstr` –› `man 1 getconf`

---

**Addendum** re [nohillside's comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210942/how-to-determine-public-temp-directory-on-os-x-to-be-write-accessible-by-www-ser/210947#comment682409_463009):

When `user` runs `stat -F $TMPDIR`, again in `bash`, under a shell - login, interactive, and? - it shows something like `drwx------ 410 user staff …`. To be clear, this is `user`'s ***incarnation*** of `TMPDIR`.

I don't know who's setting up the `TMPDIR` variable, and it is unset both in `sudo -u www bash -lic 'declare -p TMPDIR'` and an apache `httpd -V` `2.4.57` ([macports](https://ports.macports.org/port/apache2/) - not MAMP) running the `php --version` `7.4.33` script below.

So, instead of using `TMPDIR`, and still not using `/tmp`, we can get the value that `TMPDIR` would have.

When I run `stat -F $(sudo -u www getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR)` it shows `drwx------  3 _www  _www …`. Here `_www` is aka `www`.

This way, `httpd` can write to its user `www`'s ***incarnation*** of what would be `TMPDIR`, but instead retrieved by `getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR`; `user` can also read/write under the same location, depending on `user`'s configured group membership of `www` (or ACL?), or using `sudo`; all the while not having `www` use any other locations (like `/tmp`).

```php-template
<pre>
    posix_getuid                : <?=var_dump($uid      =   posix_getuid    (       )                                       )?>
    posix_getpwuid … name       : <?=var_dump(              posix_getpwuid  ($uid   )['name']                               )?>
    getenv keys                 : <?php foreach(getenv() as $k=>$v){ ?><?="\n"?>
        <?=$k?>
    <?php } ?><?="\n"?>
    shell_exec TMPDIR           : <?=var_dump(  trim(     shell_exec("           echo \$TMPDIR "                    )   )   )?>
    exec       TMPDIR           : <?=var_dump(                  exec("           echo \$TMPDIR "                        )   )?>
    shell_exec TMPDIR           : <?=var_dump(  trim(     shell_exec("bash -lic 'echo \$TMPDIR'"                    )   )   )?>
    exec       TMPDIR           : <?=var_dump(                  exec("bash -lic 'echo \$TMPDIR'"                        )   )?>
    
  Using getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR:
    shell_exec stat -F getconf …: <?=var_dump(  trim(     shell_exec("stat -F   $(getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR)"    )   )   )?>
    
  I happen to have some file there, so it's clear that "drwx------@ 3 _www" works as usual:
    shell_exec ls -l   getconf …: <?=                     shell_exec("ls -l     $(getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR)"            )?>
</pre>
```

Outputs:

```
    posix_getuid                : int(70)
    posix_getpwuid … name       : string(4) "_www"
    getenv keys                 : 
        PATH    
        XPC_SERVICE_NAME    
        XPC_FLAGS   
        XML_CATALOG_FILES   
    shell_exec TMPDIR           : string(0) ""
    exec       TMPDIR           : string(0) ""
    shell_exec TMPDIR           : string(0) ""
    exec       TMPDIR           : string(0) ""
    
  Using getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR:
    shell_exec stat -F getconf …: string(98) "drwx------ 3 _www _www 102 Aug  9 12:56:01 2023 /var/folders/…/T//"
    
  I happen to have some file there, so it's clear that "drwx------@ 3 _www" works as usual:
    shell_exec ls -l   getconf …: total 0
-rw-------  1 _www  _www  0 Aug  9 12:35 tmp.L1WG1XuJ
```

---

Bonus: Some (re)search for this answer yielded [an answer on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555058/mktemp-on-macos-not-honouring-tmpdir/555214#555214) with some other details on macOS `mktemp`, and saying the alpha numerics in `TMPDIR` comes from a base32 encoding of the equivalent of `dscl . -read /Users/$name GeneratedUID` and a "concatenation" w/ the "(BSD) user ID", so there is *another* way to calculate `TMPDIR`, but my light jab at that encoding failed, so that's left for the reader.

Comment: Doesn’t getconf just return the temp dir the OP mentioned in the question (which isn‘t accessible to Apache/httpd)

Comment: edited @nohillside

Comment: Ah, so much detail, great. Got it now, the idea is to run getconf as _www. Agreed, that will work.